# Remove duplicates and count on one column based on values from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Column A Column B
A    PASS
A    PASS
B    PASS
C    PASS
D    PASS
E   
F    PASS
E    PASS
```

I want a formula that will return the following count:
Filter by Column B for PASS.
Count all elements in column A after removing duplicates.
I am a novice at Excel formulae. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B100="Pass",IF(A2:A100<>"",MATCH(A2:A100,A2:A100,0))),ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

....shorter version, but possibly less efficient, for Excel 2007 or later versions

`=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B100="Pass")*(A2:A100<>""))/COUNTIFS(B2:B100,B2:B100&"",A2:A100,A2:A100&""))`

assumes data in rows 2 to 100 (blanks allowed), adjust as required

Comment: yes offcourse. Also can u explain me the second formula with the sumproduct. What does the COUNTIFS part do here?