# Remove duplicates and count on one column based on values from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Col A | Col B|

A     | PASS |

A     | PASS |

B     | PASS |

C     | PASS |

D     | PASS |

E     | PASS |

F

E     | PASS |

I want a formula that will return the following count:
Filter by Column B for PASS.
Count all elements in column A after removing duplicates.
I am a novice at Excel formulae. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I din get the format right the first time..I'm sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates and count on one column based on values from another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331145/remove-duplicates-and-count-on-one-column-based-on-values-from-another-column)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are trying to have a formula remove duplicates first or not but, assuming 'not', try the following:

try using autofilter first to be able to filter by column B:

**autofilter**
In Excel 2010 (I think also 2007), click on cell A1 (just once).  Then, on the menu click on Data then Filter (looks like a gray funnel).  This should enter an autofilter for all data headers in row 1 across your columns (a, b, c, d, etc).

Now, click on the drop arrow of column B and select PASS.  Now, you are sorted by cells which contain 'PASS' in Column B.

At the end of the column, in a blank cell, type: =counta(*all cells to be counted*).  Just highlight the cells you wish to include in the formula for *all cells to be counted*.  Press enter.

The count should display.

IF, you just wish to count "PASS" without sorting first, then in the blank cell just use =countif(*highlighted cells to be counted/analyzed*,"pass")

that will total the cells in the column which contain the word "pass" in it.